# FSharp.Data.SqlClient with multiple result sets

Tags: sql-server, f#, fsharp.data.sqlclient

With **FSharp.Data.SqlClient**, how do you use SqlCommandProvider or SqlProgrammabilityProvider with multiple result sets?  For instance if you wanted to get Customer+Orders where your stored procedure returns the customer info in the first result set and the orders in the second result set?

records:

```
{ OrderId=4; Date=xxx }
{ Name="Dave Smith"; Orders=[...] }
```

sp:

```
   Select Name From Customer Where CustomerId=@CustomerId
   Select OrderId, Date From Orders Where CustomerId=@CustomerId
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FSharp.Data.SqlClient is based on [sys.sp_describe_first_result_set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql). As such, it ignores second result set completely.